# Cookies is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am facing a strange problem in my CI project while trying to set value in cookie and use it. I am using this code.

```
$cookie = array(
                            'name'   => 'The Cookie Name',
                            'value'  => 'The Value',
                            'expire' => '86500',
                            'domain' => 'www.mydomain.com',
                            'path'   => '/',
                            'prefix' => 'myprefix_',
                            'secure' => TRUE
                        );

    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

and on the next line I am trying to display the value what I have store in cookies by.

```
echo $this->input->cookie('The Cookie Name');exit;
```

Not displaying anything. Can anybody give any information of this problem.

Thanks
Amar

Comment: Cookie needs to get page refresh one time. it want work in next line.

Comment: As @Rikesh said, cookies are set, but not read at the same time. So, if you want to use your cookie, you need to reload the page OR store the information in a session, that variable will be available at once.

Comment: No it is not showing even on the next page after page load

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check whether you are using cookies helper, if not, include it.

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
```

now, find out that cookie is getting set or not?

Try using `var_dump($this->input->cookie('test_cookie'));` 
and see if this return false - if so, the cookie isn't set

Any of the parameters in array can make cookie not set,
hence first use a test case-

```
$this->input->set_cookie('test_cookie', 'My cookie value');
```

I hope this will help you.